# What is "natural"?

Tags: terminology, definitions, faith, natural-philosophy

The term "natural" is often used by people who have faith in "natural" things, by marketers promoting a product, etc.

However, what is the definition of "natural"? Shouldn't everything that exist be natural, since it appeared at some point?

I'm looking for the different definitions that have been given to this term, especially when people refer to "natural" as a desirable feature.

Comment: There is a huge debate about [Natural Kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/)

Comment: But when "natural" is used as a "valutative" world, implicitly assuming that whatever is natural is "good", it relies on an unsupported notion of "good" and on the false assertion that *nature* aims at it (what about plagues, earthquakes,...?)

Comment: Two comments: Firstly, definitions are always borderline off-topic, secondly, it would help if you told why negative definitions like "not artificial", which basically are about things that would not exist without humans processing other things, do not satisfy you.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking "not artificial" raises the problem of what is "artificial"? Why would a beaver dam be more natural than a hut, for instance? At which point human "processing" sth makes this thing not being "natural" any longer?

I'm actually looking for that kind of thoughts. I understand this might not be the good place to ask, is there any other SE site where it would be more appropriate?

Comment: I've found one single book that discuss the kind of things I'm interested: "Natural: How Faith in Nature's Goodness Leads to Harmful Fads, Unjust Laws, and Flawed Science" by Alan Levinovitz.
Maybe I should read it and see what definitions of "Natural" are dscussed.

Comment: I'm not judging, just asking. For example, Plessner wrote humans were "artificial by nature", to speak in support of your intuition. It's rather to help you trim the question to be more specific and about philosophy. At the moment, there seems to be a mix of philosophical and other layers like intentional equivocation (read marketing) at play.

Comment: A similar titled question "what is information" just before yours has got 2K views  quickly while this one only got 35 views so far, is this natural or man-made?